# ERROR_CANTWRITE error from exe but not from IDE

Tags: winapi, vb6

I am using `RegSetValueExString` api to set a string value. The Registry path is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyKey`.

When i run this code from IDE, it succeeds but fails when executed from .exe and returns 5(ERROR_CANTWRITE).

I am running both IDE and .exe from Administrative privilege.
Please help.

Comment: First of all you don't want to do this.  Instead use `HKLM\Software\MyKey` and WOW64 registry virtualization will redirect it where you seem to want it.  Secondly you must be sure that your program is running elevated in order to write to most of the HKLM registry hive, just logging on as a user in the Administrators group is not enough.  Most likely you are running the IDE elevated but not your compiled program.

Comment: "*Instead use `HKLM\Software\MyKey` and WOW64 registry virtualization will redirect it where you seem to want it*" - only if your app is 32bit, or is 64bit opening the key with the `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` flag enabled.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Its a VB6 app - it has to be 32-bit

Comment: @Bob77 sure i don't want to edit `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` directly. I was trying my program on `HKLM\Software\MyKey` and it was directing to 64 bit key but change was rejected so i decided to edit the 64bit key as test and then came to know that it works with IDE but not from code. I AM running the compiled code ELEVATED, i am sure on this.

Comment: That's not right. Wow6432Node is the 32 bit section of the registry.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my mistake